Hashing password using bcrypt and node js
I'm working on a Node.js project that involves user authentication using JWT and bcrypt. I'm able to register a user successfully, but when I try to log in with the same password, I get a password mismatch error. Here is my code for the registration and login functions:
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const User = require('../models/User');

// Register a new user
const register = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { username, email, password, role = 'student' } = req.body;
  const saltRounds = 10;
  try {
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds);
    const user = new User({ username, email, password: hashedPassword, role });
    await user.save();
    res.json({ message: 'Registration successful' });
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
};

// Login with an existing user
const login = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;

  try {
    console.log('Received login request:', req.body);

    if (!username || !password) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Username and password are required' });
    }

    const user = await User.findOne({ username });
    if (!user) {
      console.log('User not found');
      return res.status(404).json({ message: 'User not found' });
    }

    console.log('Stored hashed password:', user.password);
    const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    console.log('Password match:', passwordMatch);

    if (!passwordMatch) {
      console.log('Password mismatch');
      return res.status(401).json({ message: 'Incorrect password' });
    }

    const secretKey = process.env.SECRET_KEY || 'your-hardcoded-secret-key';
    const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user._id }, secretKey, {
      expiresIn: '1h'
    });
    res.json({ token });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error logging in:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error logging in' });
  }
};

module.exports = { register, login };


I tried to register and then log in with the same password, but I'm getting a "wrong password" error. Here are some details to help with troubleshooting:
During registration, I'm hashing the password with bcrypt.
During login, I'm comparing the plain password with the hashed password stored in the database using bcrypt.compare.
I'm using a hard-coded secret key for JWT since I'm having trouble with .env file.
Debug Output:
Received login request: { username: 'safiiii', password: 'safi123' }
Stored hashed password: $2b$10$yt1UcY4zNZujN1OIYjorQuqPVvDfgfRwV218Biw4gH.k0tbzXk.MK
Password match: false
Password mismatch
Received login request: { username: 'safiiii', password: 'safi123' }
Stored hashed password: $2b$10$yt1UcY4zNZujN1OIYjorQuqPVvDfgfRwV218Biw4gH.k0tbzXk.MK
Password match: false
Password mismatch

Questions:
What could be causing the password mismatch during login?
How can I fix this issue?
Additional Info:
Node.js version: 14.x
Bcrypt version: 5.0.1
JWT version: 8.5.1
Database: MongoDB
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

How did you define User Schema ? Please share the User model schema.

I had the same problem with bcrypt. I was using that method:
public async signIn(email: string, pass: string): Promise<{ access_token: string }> {
        this.logger.log(`email and password from controller signIn(): ${email} - ${pass}`)
      
        try {
          const { user, found } = await this.usersService.findOneByEmail(email);
          if(!found || !user) throw new UnauthorizedException('Invalid credentials');
      
          this.logger.log(`Hash password stored: ${user.password}`);
          this.logger.log(`Password provided: ${pass}`);
      
const isPasswordMatching = await bcrypt.compare(pass, user.password);
      this.logger.log(Resultado da comparação da senha: ${isPasswordMatching});
if (!isPasswordMatching) throw new UnauthorizedException('Invalid credentials')
        
          const payload: AccessTokenPayload = {
            sub: user.id,
            email: user.email,
          };
      
          const accessToken = await this.jwtService.signAsync(payload, {
            secret: this.configService.get<string>('JWT_SECRET'),
            expiresIn: this.configService.get<string>('EXPIRES_IN')
          });
      
          return { access_token: accessToken };
      
        } catch(error) {
          this.logger.error(`Erro no método signIn()`, error.message);
          throw error;
        }
      }

And the error was that the password that I was providing was invalid. I'm using bycrpt version 5.1.1 and the database is PostgreSQL.
Then, I tried to use the callback version of compare(), and changed the method to use this:
bcrypt.compare(pass, user.password, (err) => {
    console.log("erro: ", err.message);
  });

With that modification everything works! I don't why, but maybe this can resolve your issue.
